# Creating a large Mega Menu with CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, nav

I am trying to create a mega menu like those at http://rackspace.com. I have tried the tutorials given at some of the other questions about this already asked, but one of them used a lot of images, and one of them didn't work with the version of jQuery they linked to. I would like to keep this all CSS, but if I must I could use some JavaScript.

I don't understand how to make complex mega menu's but only the simple drop-down's. If someone could provide me with the code for this I would be very happy. I am learning CSS now and I think this will allow me to sharpen my knowledge as well.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Another question I looked at had this JS Fiddle in it, but when copying it over to my actual page, it did not function, plus, it uses a <span> tag which could cause a problem if I go to adding a lot of links as that will get annoying. Anyways, here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hgZGS/

Comment: That fiddle uses the jquery library; did you make sure to include the library in your document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extremely quick sample of what you need to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/KqZd4/

I know this looks nothing like those, but that really is all the functionality you need. Just expand what is in the dropdown

Comment: Quick question on this. When I use it and set the width of the ".sub li" to 1000px it moves the next menu icon over as shown in this screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/YbUY3.png how would I keep that from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very nice looking solution a quick Google search turned up. Haven't tried it myself but looks promising: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

Comment: I used that for one of my other sites. It was good, but I am looking for a blank slate with just the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too general. What you're trying to achieve is not going to happen with a simple HTML and CSS code that we can write here.

So you may be interested in this this jQuery plugin and CSS framework:
https://myflashlabs.github.io/24component-bars/

It helps you to create responsive mega menu, header, sidebar, and footer with lots functionalities fast and easy, without any hassle... It's exactly what you want :)

**You don't need to code it yourself all from the beginning when there's already a solution out there!**

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="main_list">Electronics
<ul>
<p class="category_header">Buy Any Electronics Item And Get Flat 50% OFF</p>
<ol>
<li>Mobiles</li>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>Tablets</li>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
</ol>

</ul>
</li>
```

add more you want

then simple style

```
#main_menu
{
background-color:#1C1C1C;
float:left;
padding:0px;
width:700px;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
margin-left:140px;
border-radius:5px;
}
#main_menu .main_list
{
color:white;
list-style-type:none;
float:left;
border-left:1px solid #666;
padding-left:27px;
padding-right:27px;

}
#main_menu .main_list:hover
{
color:#2E9AFE;
}
.main_list ul
{
background-color:white;
width:600px;
position:absolute;
left:150px;
width:700px;
padding:0px;
float:left;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
.main_list ul p
{
color:white;
background-color:#2E9AFE;
margin:0px;
text-align:left;
padding-left:10px;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}
.main_list ul ol
{
float:left;
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;
margin-left:30px;
}
.main_list ul ol li
{
line-height:25px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px;
color:#2E9AFE;
}
```

if you have any problem understanding here is a complete tutorial
http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/mega-dropdown-menu-like-ecommerce-using-css.php

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Style Navigation bar */
.navbar {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 1.1em 1em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.navbar > a:hover, .dropdown > a:hover {
  border-bottom-color: #FA7D19;
}

/* Style Mega Menu */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content .header {
  padding: 16px;
  color: #777;
  background: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that stacks next to each other */
.row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.column a {
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of 
   next to each other (when screen width is 600px or less) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
      </div>   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 1</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 2</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 3</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#">Pricing</a>
</div>

<div style="padding:10px 15px;">
  <h1>Create a Mega Menu</h1>
  <p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the mega menu.</p>
</div>
```

**Reference:**[How To Create a Mega Menu](https://parrot-tutorial.com/howto/howto_mega_menu.html)